# In zsh, how do you bind a key to a string, not a function?

Tags: zsh, key-bindings, zshrc

Sometimes its very useful to bind a key to insert a string. Bash uses readline, so I have these two bindings in my `~/.inputrc` that I find very useful:

```
"\C-xp": "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"
"\C-xf": "find /src -maxdepth 5 -type f -name '*.py' | xargs grep -En "
```

I've been messing around with zsh lately, but I can't figure out how to get this behavior. Is there some magic form of `bindkey` that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZSH manual: 4.5.4: Binding strings instead of commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html#l97) says:

> It's possible to assign an arbitrary string of characters to a key sequence instead of an editor command by giving bindkey the option -s.